# JAVAFX: Loading the image from the database

Tags: java, sql, javafx

I need some help regarding image loading from database. How do I retrieve the image from the database and put it in an Image/ImageView?

Thank you very much!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This is `JavaFX` and not Swing !! ;-)

Comment: I know.  Fortunately it doesn't take knowledge of Java-FX to spot a question on which the OP has invested/displayed 0 effort whatsoever.. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Resolved ! Posted an SSCCE for the OP

Comment: @LittleChild  That's nice ..for the OP ..in the short term.  I'm just not so sure that spoon-feeding them a solution is the best thing for either the SO community at large *or* the OP in the long term.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well, I didnt *make* the SSCCE, it is from the docs. Pointing there or posting here is one and he same :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageOpsTest extends Application {

    // Image Data
    private static final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 10;
    private static final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 10;
    private byte imageData[] = 
        new byte[IMAGE_WIDTH * IMAGE_HEIGHT * 3];

    // Drawing Surface (Canvas)
    private GraphicsContext gc;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Group root;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("PixelWriter Test");
        root = new Group();
        canvas = new Canvas(200, 200);
        canvas.setTranslateX(100);
        canvas.setTranslateY(100);
        gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        createImageData();
        drawImageData();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void createImageData() {
        int i = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < IMAGE_HEIGHT; y++) {
            int r = y * 255 / IMAGE_HEIGHT;
            for (int x = 0; x < IMAGE_WIDTH; x++) {
                int g = x * 255 / IMAGE_WIDTH;
                imageData[i] = (byte) r;
                imageData[i + 1] = (byte) g;
                i += 3;
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawImageData() {
        boolean on = true;
        PixelWriter pixelWriter = gc.getPixelWriter();
        PixelFormat<ByteBuffer> pixelFormat = PixelFormat.getByteRgbInstance();
        for (int y = 50; y < 150; y += IMAGE_HEIGHT) {
            for (int x = 50; x < 150; x += IMAGE_WIDTH) {
                if (on) {
                    pixelWriter.setPixels(x, y, IMAGE_WIDTH,
                            IMAGE_HEIGHT, pixelFormat, imageData, 
                            0, IMAGE_WIDTH * 3);
                }
                on = !on;
            }
            on = !on;
        }

        // Add drop shadow effect
        gc.applyEffect(new DropShadow(20, 20, 20, Color.GRAY));
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    }
}
```

This [example taken from the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/image_ops/jfxpub-image_ops.htm) demonstrates how you can **create** an image out of `byte[]`. When you store image into the database, you get them back as `byte[]`.
Now, how you retrieve the image from the database is completely up to you but once you retrieve it, you can use the program above to convert it into an image.

Comment: Thank you. But can this be also implemented in an ImageView?